# How to throw an Exception inside a Try/Catch block?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following Java method:

```
public Class createClass(Class class) {
    try {
        // retrieve the professor of the class and check if he exists
        Professor professorFound = professorRepository.findById(class.getProfessorId());
        if (professorFound != null) {
           // if the professor exists, then check if he already has a class
           // with the same id
           List<Class> classes = professorFound.getClasses();
           List<Class> classFound = classes.stream().... // loop to find the class... 

           // if he has, throw an exception
           if(!classFound.isEmpty()) {
                throw new ClassAlreadyRegisteredException();

           } else {
                // if he does not have, then create the class
                Class class = new Class();
                professorFound.getClasses().add(class);
                return professorRepository.save(professorFound);
           }
        } else {
           // if the professor does not exist, throw an exception
           throw new ProfessorNotFoundException();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if there is any other error during the communication with the database, 
        // throw a generic IOException
        throw new ClassIOException();
    }
}
```

Basically, what I need is to throw specific Exceptions (if the professor informed in the request does not exist, or if the professor already has a class with the same id), or throw a generic `IOException` if there is any other error during the communication with the database.

However, in the way that I have developed, if any specific `Exception` is thrown, the try block will catch the exception and will throw a generic IOException.

How can I solve this problem?

**I'm very interested in understanding what are the best practices in this case.**
**Should I catch each specific exception separately and throw them twice?**
**Is that a good practice?**

**EDIT:**

This is how my `ClassAlreadyRegisteredException` looks like:

```
public class ClassAlreadyRegisteredException extends ApiException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ClassAlreadyRegisteredException(String code, String message, String developerMessage, String origin, HttpStatus status) {
        super(code,message,developerMessage,origin, status);
    }
}
```

This is how my `ApiException` looks like:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class ApiException extends RuntimeException{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private String code;
    private String userMessage;
    private String developerMessage;
    private String origin;
    private HttpStatus status;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You absolutely should change the name of your `Class` class; never name a class the same thing as anything in `java.lang`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Actually `Class` and `Professor` are not the original names of the classes; I have used this names in order to better explain the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Checked vs Unchecked Exceptions

It's totally acceptable to throw an exception in a catch block. A common use case is to take a checked `Exception` and throw a unchecked `RuntimeException` which would allow the exception bubble up to where it needs to be handled.

You'll want to use checked exceptions for use cases such as Connectivity/IO, SQL exceptions..

#### Handling Checked Exceptions

To answer your question, in most libraries that connect to the database, an checked `IOException` is thrown if there are any connectivity issues. For these cases, you can always specify this in the method signature `public Class createClass() throws IOException`

this specifies that any callers of `createClass()` has to fulfill the contract that the `IOException` is handled.

or

You can rethrow this as a `RuntimeException`

```
try {
   ...
} catch (IOException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e); // <- send the original exception so you can preserve the exception and stacktrace.
}
```

This will essentially bubble up to STDOUT or whatever handler your framework specifies.

#### CAUTION:

However, catching an cover all `Exception` and throwing a more specific `ClassIOException` can have unintended consequences.

If you have a `NullPointerException` this will be captured by your `catch (Exception e)` block and rethrown as a `ClassIOException`

Doing this will corrupt the stacktrace and cause your error logs to be much more difficult to debug.

#### Understanding what constitutes an checked Exceptions.

Another tip is to consider what your `Exception` cases are.

If they are standard flow of the application, service, or business logic -- these may not be appropriate exceptions.

The `ClassAlreadyRegisteredException` and `ProfessorNotFoundException` may not be exceptional cases in your application... unless these are already specified by your professor.

Sometimes these can be thrown as `RuntimeException` if the situation calls for it.

#### Best Practices?

There are still many opinions on how exceptions are handled. So here are some rule of thumb questions I ask myself when working with exceptions

1. Is the stacktrace preserved? Will I be able to trace back to the root Exception
2. Is this common logic and represents an exceptional case that deviates from what my application provides?
3. If I throw this exception, is it an absolute necessity for anything calling this method to handle this exceptional logic?

Comment: Could please elaborate more this sentence: "The `ClassAlreadyRegisteredException` and `ProfessorNotFoundException` may not be exceptional cases in your application... unless these are already specified by your professor." ? What are the alteratives if I don't handle them as Exceptions?

Comment: You mentioned that if I have a `NullPointerException` (considering the original code), I would throw a `ClassIOException`. What would be the best solution in this case?

Comment: Please, leave your suggestion on how you would refactor the code, considering your explanation.

Comment: Your ClassAlreadyRegisteredException and ProfessorNotFoundException is fine in it's current state. However since you area using Java8 it would be an appropriate usecase for `Optional`

Comment: A NullPointerException should never be rethrown as a ClassIOException. Typically a catch block that catches `Exception` or `Throwable` is too big of a safety net that would cause side effects like this.

Comment: What does ClassAlreadyRegisteredException or ProfessorNotFoundException extend from?

Comment: I have added the Exception classes to my question.

Comment: Such a nice Explanation in clear language. Loved it

Answer (score 6):

Catch and re-throw.

```
try {
   ... same as before ...
} catch (ClassAlreadyRegisteredException | ProfessorNotFoundException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // if there is any other error during the communication with the database, 
    // throw a generic IOException
    throw new ClassIOException();
}
```

Alternatively, remember the exception to throw it later.

```
 Exception fail = null;

 try {
      ….
     // save exception in place of existing throws
     // for example:
     fail = new ClassAlreadyRegisteredException();
     …
 } catch (Exception ex) {
     ...same as original...
 }

 if (fail != null) {
     throw fail;
 }
```

I use both techniques; the choice depends on what is simpler in any given situation.  Neither is uncontestably better.

For the catch and re-throw method, you have to keep the list of caught-and-rethrown exceptions consistent with the exceptions you actually throw from within the try-clause.   In larger cases, I'd avoid that problem by using an exception hierarchy, so I could catch the common base class.

For the save-and-throw method, you have to arrange control flow so that nothing significant is done after detecting the failure, since you don't have the immediate 'throw' command to exit the try-clause.  Nevertheless there are cases where it is simple enough; the original example is one such.

Comment: What is the advantage of using the second technique?

Comment: Answer updated to add rationale, but it's just that in some cases it results in code that's easier to follow.  A lot of programming is an aesthetic judgment, not the application of fixed rules.